# Git - phantom local commits

Tags: git, github

We're using Github. Once in a while, after a `git pull`, I run `git status` and am told that I'm ahead of `origin/master`, which is odd, because I think I've committed everything. So I do a `git push`.

Sure enough, there's nothing to push. So I run `git status` again, and this time the "phantom local commits" are gone; I'm not ahead of `origin/master` after all.

My team mates have experienced this, too. We've only noticed it since we started using Github.

**Any idea what's going on here?**

Below is an example from my terminal, just after I did a `git pull`.

```
~/projects/formula[master]% git status
# On branch master
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 2 commits.
#
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
~/projects/formula[master]% git push origin master
Everything up-to-date
~/projects/formula[master]% git status
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
~/projects/formula[master]%
```

Comment: You can list these commits with `git log [--pretty=oneline] master...origin/master`

Answer (score 1):

Did you try the following?

```
git remote update orgin
```

It will update the status of your remote `origin`. You can also omit `origin` and update all your remotes at once.

Comment: Interesting. What does this actually do? The only communication I know about between repos is pushing and pulling.

Comment: `remote update` will `fetch` the configured branch(es) of the specified remote. See `remote.<name>.fetch` at http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html.